# Android Animate BackgroundColor in TextView

Tags: java, android, animation

does anyone know, why this code doesn't work and how fix it? I'm trying animate background color of `TextView`. IDE doesn't show error.

```
private void animationButton(final TextView textView) {

    int firstColor = Color.parseColor("FFFFFFFF");
    int secondColor = Color.parseColor("FF00FF00");

    ValueAnimator animation = new ValueAnimator();
    animation.setIntValues(firstColor, secondColor);
    animation.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

    animation.setDuration(300);

    animation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            textView.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });

    animation.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IDE doesn't show error

Then I'm assuming you're surrounding `animationButton` in a `try-catch` block and not logging anything because [`Color.parseColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)) requires a `#` to parse hex color codes. You should be getting an `IllegalArgumentException` with the code you posted.

**From the docs**

> Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the
>   string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception.
>   Supported formats are:
>
> `#RRGGBB`
>
> `#AARRGGBB`

Otherwise you need to pass in one of the following values:

> red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow,
>   lightgray, darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime,
>   maroon, navy, olive, purple, silver, and teal.

**Source**

```
@ColorInt
public static int parseColor(@Size(min=1) String colorString) {
    if (colorString.charAt(0) == '#') {
        // Use a long to avoid rollovers on #ffXXXXXX
        long color = Long.parseLong(colorString.substring(1), 16);
        if (colorString.length() == 7) {
            // Set the alpha value
            color |= 0x00000000ff000000;
        } else if (colorString.length() != 9) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
        }
        return (int)color;
    } else {
        Integer color = sColorNameMap.get(colorString.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
        if (color != null) {
            return color;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
}
```